# Copying (cloning) an array of objects of type of wrapper classes

Tags: java, arrays

I understand how the System.arraycopy() and Arrays.copyOf() methods work for copying arrays of primitive and reference types. But I got the following mess in the code.

```
Integer[] integer = new Integer[] {4, 17, 5, 8, 22};
Integer[] integer1 = Arrays.copyOf(integer, integer.length);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(integer));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(integer1));

integer[1] = 455;

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(integer));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(integer1));
```

Result :

```
[4, 17, 5, 8, 22]
[4, 17, 5, 8, 22]

[4, 455, 5, 8, 22]
[4, 17, 5, 8, 22]
```

Since wrapper classes are reference data types, when copying arrays of a reference type using the Arrays.copyOf () method, and subsequently changing an element in one of the copies, the changes must affect both arrays. Why is this not so in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Wrapper object will not change its primitive typed value. Rather the variable is replaced with a new wrapper object.

```
Integer x = 300; // The variable x will contain an Integer wrapper of the int 400.
x = 400; // The variable x will contain a new Integer wrapper of the int 400.
```

This happens:

```
Integer x = Integer.valueOf(300);
x = Integer.valueOf(400);
```

In java variables, as also fields, array slots, will hold - as value - a primitive type or - as here - an object. Assigning will replace the variable's value.

Comment: With strings the same situation?

Answer (score 0):

To make a copy of an array to have it affect both arrays 
You use this

```
    int[] x = new int[n];
    int[] y = x;
```

if you want to make a copy of the value of a element that is storing a value I would use .copyOf() other wise use this!
This explain arrays better than me!

https://books.trinket.io/thinkjava2/chapter7.html

Answer (score 0):

Because they're distinct arrays.

If you instead wrote `Integer[] integer1 = integer`, then it would be the case that if `integer[1]` was replaced by another value, the value of `integer1[1]` was also replaced, because those two variables would refer to the same object.

But the whole point of `Arrays.copyOf` is that the array is cloned, so the two arrays are distinct. Changing a value in one of the arrays would not change the contents of the other.

Answer (score 0):

If the array is of a primitive type or immutable type, then when using the copy methods `Arrays.copyOf()` and changing an element in one of the arrays, the other array will not be affected. But if the array is a complex reference type (for example, `Human`) (mutable), then the changes will affect both arrays.

It is precisely for this reason that changes to the wrapper type array do not appear on another array.